# Find mean and sd of red and blue colour values in video

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I have video files that I can convert into RGB space with`cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` for each frame.

I then want to calculate the mean value and standard deviation of red and blue colour values, averaged and sd'ed over a 100sec period. My videos are >100sec long, so would want to repeat this for every 100 seconds and assign the values to a vector.
So for every n'th 100 second clip, I have values R(ave), R(sd), B(ave), B(sd).

I am fairly new to CV and video processing, so would appreciate help in any part of this.

Comment: do you have any code? or have you watched any lessons about cv2?

Comment: @crackanddie done basic lessons but nothing covers this exactly. my code is admittedly bare at the moment, so would appreciate a nudge in the right direction. Ik I can get `colours = cv2.imread(frame, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    b,g,r = (colours[300, 300])` for each frame

Comment: ok, if you are not in a hurry, I will work on it tomorrow

Comment: @crackanddie <3 no big hurry, you are my saviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally wrote it. This whole program will run long enough on videos that are over 1 minute long. And if you have a weak computer, then I do not envy you. But generally it works well enough. Here it is:

```py
import cv2


def calc_sd(arr: list, mean_val: float):
    prev_dis = 0
    for k in arr:
        prev_dis += (k - mean_val) ** 2
    dis = prev_dis / len(arr)
    return dis ** (1 / 2)


def calc_mean(arr: list):
    return sum(arr) / len(arr)


# list of your videos here
lst_of_videos = ['vid_test.mkv', 'signs.mkv', 'signs_ml.mkv']
lst_of_all_videos_data = []

for i in lst_of_videos:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)

    # list for data every 100 sec
    # data there will be like:
    # [['mean_red', 'mean_green', 'mean_blue', 'sd_red', 'sd_green', 'sd_blue'], 'and every 100 sec like this']
    lst_of_data = []

    lst_of_red = []
    lst_of_green = []
    lst_of_blue = []

    # getting video fps
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    abstract_seconds = 0  # for counting frames

    print('video: ', i)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if abstract_seconds >= 100 or not ret:
            print(' video: ', i, ', 100 secs, ret: ', ret)
            mean_red = calc_mean(lst_of_red)
            mean_green = calc_mean(lst_of_green)
            mean_blue = calc_mean(lst_of_blue)
            print('  mean counted')

            sd_red = calc_sd(lst_of_red, mean_red)
            sd_green = calc_sd(lst_of_green, mean_green)
            sd_blue = calc_sd(lst_of_blue, mean_blue)
            print('  sd counted')

            lst_of_data.append([mean_red, mean_green, mean_blue, sd_red, sd_green, sd_blue])
            lst_of_red.clear()
            lst_of_green.clear()
            lst_of_blue.clear()
            print('  arrays cleared')

            if not ret:
                break

        b, g, r = cv2.split(frame)
        lst_of_red.append(r.sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0) / r.size)
        lst_of_green.append(g.sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0) / g.size)
        lst_of_blue.append(b.sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0) / b.size)

        abstract_seconds += 1 / fps

    print(lst_of_data)
    lst_of_all_videos_data.append(lst_of_data)
    lst_of_data.clear()
```

Comment: clear, concise and infinitely helpful, thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I will use something like the following code to compute the global stats of 1 hour videos.

I modified it directly in the stackoverflow box to meet your "time windows" requirement, so it may have some minor errors.
I dropped the last segments because you said you want 100s seconds windows but you can adapt it easily if you really need it.

I kept the BGR format because it is as good as any other.

I like this option more than the other answer because you are not keeping a lot of lists and mean and standard computation is done for the 3 channels in one go.

Another important point is the release of the opened videos.

```
from docopt import docopt
from contextlib import contextmanager
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys


@contextmanager
def VideoCapture(input_video):

    # findFileOrKeep allows more searching paths
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.samples.findFileOrKeep(input_video))
    if not capture.isOpened():
        print('Unable to open: ' + input_video, file=sys.stderr)
        exit(0)

    try:
        yield capture
    finally:
        # Release the video capture object at the end
        capture.release()


DOCTEXT = f"""
Usage:
  name_of_the_script.py <video_path>... [--windows=<w>]

Options:
  --windows=<w>    Windows seconds [default: 100]
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':

    args = docopt(DOCTEXT, argv=sys.argv[1:], help=True, version=None, options_first=False)
    video_pathes = args['<video_path>']
    windows = float(args['--windows'])
    

    output = []
    for i_video, video_path in enumerate(video_pathes):
        with VideoCapture(video_path) as cap:
    
            fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
            i = 0

            psum    = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]) # BGR
            psum_sq = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]) # BGR
            num_px  = windows * fps * int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)) * cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

            while True:
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                if not ret: # frame is None
                    break
    
                fr += 1
                if fr % int(windows * fps) == 0:
                    print(f'Processed {fr / fps}s\tVideo {i_video} / len(video_pathes)\t{video_path}')
                    
                    total_mean = psum / num_px
                    total_var  = (psum_sq / num_px) - (total_mean ** 2)
                    total_std  = np.sqrt(total_var)

                    output.append([total_mean, total_std])

                    psum    = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]) # BGR
                    psum_sq = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]) # BGR

                psum = frame.sum(axis=(0, 1))
                psum_sq = (frame ** 2).sum(axis=(0, 1))

    print(f'[mean (BGR), std (BGR)]:\n{output}') # NOTE: or use it as you want. You should make it as a function if you need it to do another thing.
```